# Error message when sending embed discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

here is my code:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async(msg) => {
if (msg.content.startsWith('do avatar')) {
const user = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
const avatarEmbed = new discord_js_1.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(0x333333)
  .setTitle(`${user.username}'s Avatar`)
  .setImage(`https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${user.id}/${user.avatar}.png?size=256`
  );
msg.channel.send({ embed: [avatarEmbed] });
}
  });
```

and here is my error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Typo: it should be `embeds: [avatarEmbed]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have are using `embed` property while sending the message, that doesn't exist. It should be embed**s**